# What does the "?." operator do in c#?

Tags: c#, events

I've encountered this operator in C# when dealing with custom events: `MyEvent?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());`.  What is the purpose of the `?.` portion of this statement?

Comment: Yup, definitely a dup.  For some reason that question didn't come up when I searched... the syntax seems to bugger up the search engine for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to find what operators mean in C#. The best place to look is the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) then at least you get the right name to search for.

Answer (score -1):

It's making sure it's not null. They have these in swift and their called optionals. If the variable is null then it returns null

Comment: It most definitely is not an option type, it's a null coalescing operator.